# cURL PHP always returns to homepage

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the cURL to reload a new page after I click a link but the only thing that change is the url and not the page it self (look below to see what I mean)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXQ4U.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxUuw.png

Here is my code

```
    <?php
//create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

//set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if ($output === FALSE) {
  echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
//close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
   /**
     * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
     * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
     */
    function get_web_page( $url )
    {
        $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

        $options = array(

            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
            CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header['content'] = $content;
        return $header;
    }



?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This is very unclear - and what is the function for?  You should be CLEAR in your request as to what it is you are trying to achieve and give clear "I tried this with this code and it did this, but I thought it should do that" sort of questions.

Comment: @CFPSupport Thanks for the reply. What am trying to do is reprint the page to the new clicked target page for example if I visit localhost.com it will print the home page and if I click localhost.com/test (or any other links) I want it to print that page instead of the home page. I hope I was more clear in this one. Please let me know if you need more details to better understand what am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here is a test site (http://anipush.x10.mx/) when you click a post/link it just refreshes on the landing page. I want it to do what I have mention above.

Comment: It might be .htaccess I remove it then it redirect to 404 not found when I clicked localhost.com/test. Here what my .htaccess looks like, `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`  also I have  the mention code in a file called index.php and upload to the root directory.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for what am facing. Any input would be greatly appreciated.